# How do I set the background color of a styled div using a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to set a background color of a react component which uses a styled div.

I'm receiving the color value from another service, the `<div>` is styled as follows:

```
const ContainerDiv = style.div `
  background: backgroundColor;
`;
```

Where I am getting the `backgroundColor` from the service and I have verified that it is returning the correct value:

```
#FFFFFF
```

However when I use the above code the background color does not change but if I hard code the value to `#FFFFFF` then the background color changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `props` with a styled component you have to use a template expression and pass it a function.  That function will be passed your `props`, and whatever your function returns will be added to the CSS.  Inside it you can create whatever CSS string you want using those `props`.

For instance:

```
const ContainerDiv = style.div `
    ${props => `background: ${background};`}
`;
```